Error executing DDL for foreign key constraint in Hibernate with MySQL
I'm encountering an issue with Hibernate while trying to define a foreign key constraint for a MySQL database in my Spring Boot application.
I have three entities: Promoteur, Projet, and Bien. The Projet and Bien entities have a ManyToOne relationship with Promoteur. When Hibernate tries to create the foreign key constraint for Bien referencing Promoteur, it fails with the following error:
Error executing DDL "alter table bien add constraint FKqgqkp7ivcjlsui7iwreav2tnl foreign key (promoteur_id) references promoteur (id)" via JDBC [Can't create table `test20`.`bien` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")]
The entities and their relationships are correctly annotated with @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn. The Promoteur entity is defined with an @Id annotated field for its primary key, and both Projet and Bien correctly reference Promoteur using @ManyToOne.
  @Entity
  public class Promoteur {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;
      @NotEmpty
      private String nomPromoteur;
      @NotEmpty
      private String contact;
  }

  @Entity
  public class Projet {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;
      @NotEmpty
      private String nomProjet;
      @NotNull
      private Integer consistance;
      @NotNull
      @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
      private EtatProjet etat;
      @NotNull
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "promoteur_id")
      private Promoteur promoteur;
      // Other fields and relationships
  }

  @Entity
  public class Bien {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;
      private String refPromoteur;
      @NotNull
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "promoteur_id")
      private Promoteur promoteur;
      @NotNull
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "projet_id")
      private Projet projet;
      // Other fields and constraints
  }

I suspect the issue might be related to the way Hibernate is interpreting the foreign key constraint for Bien referencing Promoteur.
How can I resolve this errno: 150 error and successfully create the foreign key constraint in MySQL using Hibernate?
